# Get an io.ByteReader from a net.Conn

Tags: go

I am connecting to a TCP/IP server using Go code similar to:

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host+":"+strconv.Itoa(port))
```

Now I need to use [binary.ReadVariant](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ReadVarint) which takes an io.ByteReader, so trying to write code like this:

```
var length int64
var err error
length, err = binary.ReadVarint(conn)
```

Gives me an error like:

```
./main.go:67: cannot use conn (type net.Conn) as type io.ByteReader in function argument:
    net.Conn does not implement io.ByteReader (missing ReadByte method)
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the underlying [*net.TCPConn*](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn) returned by *net.Dial* as *net.Conn* only implements the *`Read(byte[]) (int, err)`* method. This means that the returned *net.Conn* satisfies the *io.Reader* interface, but it does not satisfy the *io.ByteReader* interface because *net.TCPConn* doesn't have a *`ReadByte() (c byte, err error)`* method.

You can use the [*bufio.NewReader*](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewReader) function to wrap the *net.Conn* in a type that does implement the *io.ByteReader* interface.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "google.com:80")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")

    length, err := binary.ReadVarint(bufio.NewReader(conn))
    if err != nil {
    panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(length)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[bufio.Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader) implements the [ByteReader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ByteReader) interface.

Wrapping `conn` using `bufio.NewReader(conn)` should work.